# Get all my questions from database and then choose which one based on ID

Tags: php, ajax

I have a database with all my questions in it. Each question is a yes/no question. 
The program starts with the question with ID 1. If yes is clicked for this question, then go to question with ID 2, if no is clicked go to question with ID of 10.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "mobiledatabase");
$question_id = rand(1,100);

$query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question_id' ";
$query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$query_row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run); 

if ($query_row==1) { 
     foreach ($query_run as $row ) {
          $id_question = $row['id'];
          $question = $row['question']; 
        } 
    }
```

By doing this I can select one question at random. But I can't get another one without reloading the page. 
What I want is to get all my questions and then choose which one without reloading the page.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "mobiledatabase");
$query = "SELECT * FROM adult_questions"; 
$result = $connection->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["id"]." ".$row["question"]."<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

I tried something like this but this just shows them all at the same time.

The solution will maybe be a bit to complicated to post here(?) but then just give me a hint to what I should do please. Should I put them in a json file, an xml file?

Comment: if you do not reload page then use ajax

Comment: Sounds like you should use javascript.

Comment: you need AJAX. .

Comment: if you want to show first one question then click first then second ....?

Comment: ajax tutorials it will be then, thx